# How to stream elastic beanstalk's custom log to Cloudwatch?

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I set up a AWS elasticbeanstalk environment, and the platform is Tomcat. Now my requirement is to stream Tomcat log `catalina.out` to AWS Cloudwatch. By following official docs, I got the following results:

If I deploy a single  `war` file, with a .ebextensions folder in its root folder, I can find `catalina.out` in Cloudwatch, it works!

But If I deploy a `zip` file, and its structure is:

`app.zip
  - .ebextensions
  - app1.war
  - app2.war`

I cannot find the log in Cloudwatch!

And my .config file in the .ebextensions folder is written as:

`` files:
  "/etc/awslogs/config/beanstalklogs_custom.conf":
    mode: "000600"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      [/var/log/tomcat8/catalina.out]
      log_group_name = `{"Fn::Join":["/", ["/aws/elasticbeanstalk", { "Ref":"AWSEBEnvironmentName" }, "var/log/tomcat8/catalina.out"]]}`
      log_stream_name = {instance_id}
      file = /var/log/tomcat8/catalina.out* ``

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AWS Appender](https://github.com/kdgregory/log4j-aws-appenders) to write your application logs to CloudWatch. To use this with Elastic Beankstalk you need to add permissions to the execution role that Elastic Beanstalk is using. Check your [Elastic Beanstalk Instant profile](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/concepts-roles-instance.html)

Answer (score 0):

I've detailed in a new [Medium blog](https://codingrob.medium.com/how-to-setup-aws-elasticbeanstalk-to-stream-your-custom-application-logs-to-cloudwatch-d5c877eaa242) how this all works and an example .ebextensions file and **where** to put it.

[image: location in Java Web application]

Below is an excerpt that you might be able to use, though the article explains how to determine the right folder/file(s) to stream.

```
packages:
  yum:
    awslogs: []

option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:cloudwatch:logs
    option_name: StreamLogs
    value: true
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:cloudwatch:logs
    option_name: DeleteOnTerminate
    value: false
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:cloudwatch:logs
    option_name: RetentionInDays
    value: 90

files:
  "/etc/awslogs/awscli.conf" :
    mode: "000600"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      [plugins]
      cwlogs = cwlogs
      [default]
      region = `{"Ref":"AWS::Region"}`

  "/etc/awslogs/config/logs.conf" :
    mode: "000600"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      [/var/log/tomcat/localhost.log]
      log_group_name = `{"Fn::Join":["/", ["/aws/elasticbeanstalk", { "Ref":"AWSEBEnvironmentName" }, "var/log/tomcat/localhost.log"]]}`
      log_stream_name = {instance_id}
      file = /var/log/tomcat/localhost.*

      [/var/log/tomcat/catalina.log]
      log_group_name = `{"Fn::Join":["/", ["/aws/elasticbeanstalk", { "Ref":"AWSEBEnvironmentName" }, "var/log/tomcat/catalina.log"]]}`
      log_stream_name = {instance_id}
      file = /var/log/tomcat/catalina.*

      [/var/log/tomcat/localhost_access_log.txt]
      log_group_name = `{"Fn::Join":["/", ["/aws/elasticbeanstalk", { "Ref":"AWSEBEnvironmentName" }, "var/log/tomcat/access_log"]]}`
      log_stream_name = {instance_id}
      file = /var/log/tomcat/access_log.*

commands:
  "01":
    command: systemctl enable awslogsd.service
  "02":
    command: systemctl restart awslogsd
```